# Chart.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, chart.js

Edited the Details as I found a solution to display the Chart with the right datasets. Code Below will show the Two Charts, which visually looks great but buttons on the 1st Chart are working great but the buttons on 2nd chart are not working.

Please check my code and Run the code Snippet and see by clicking on Today Monthly Yearly Buttons on both 1st and 2nd chart and you will find the error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'options')
> at timeFrame2 (Index:1825:41)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Index:708:165)

**Heres the Code:**

```js
//for Miscellaneous
const day = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 18
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-02 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-03 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 6
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-04 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 9
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-05 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-06 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-07 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 9
  },
];
const month = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-01-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-02-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-03-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 10
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-04-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 5
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-06-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-07-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 15
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-08-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 0
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-09-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 60
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-10-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 55
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-11-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-12-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 10
  },
];
const year = [{
    x: '2018',
    y: '15'
  },
  {
    x: '2019',
    y: '5'
  },
  {
    x: '2020',
    y: '25'
  },
  {
    x: '2021',
    y: '50'
  },
  {
    x: '2022',
    y: '40'
  },
];
//for Administrative
const day1 = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-02 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 18
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-03 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 9
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-04 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 6
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-05 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-06 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-07 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 7
  },
];
const month1 = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-01-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-02-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 0
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-03-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 13
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-04-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 4
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-06-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-07-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-08-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-09-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-10-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 50
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-11-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-12-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
];
const year1 = [{
    x: '2018',
    y: '40'
  },
  {
    x: '2019',
    y: '50'
  },
  {
    x: '2020',
    y: '25'
  },
  {
    x: '2021',
    y: '5'
  },
  {
    x: '2022',
    y: '15'
  },
];
//for Payroll
const day2 = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 14
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-02 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 16
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-03 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-04 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 9
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-05 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 2
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-06 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 10
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-07 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 12
  },
];
const month2 = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-01-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 10
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-02-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-03-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-04-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-06-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-07-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 10
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-08-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-09-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 10
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-10-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 0
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-11-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-12-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 60
  },
];
const year2 = [{
    x: '2018',
    y: '50'
  },
  {
    x: '2019',
    y: '40'
  },
  {
    x: '2020',
    y: '15'
  },
  {
    x: '2021',
    y: '25'
  },
  {
    x: '2022',
    y: '5'
  },
];
//for PettyCash
const day3 = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 13
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-02 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 14
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-03 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 10
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-04 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 11
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-05 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 16
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-06 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 15
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-07 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 10
  },
];
const month3 = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-01-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 17
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-02-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-03-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 50
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-04-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-06-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-07-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 5
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-08-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 15
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-09-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-10-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 58
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-11-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 33
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-12-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 18
  },
];
const year3 = [{
    x: '2018',
    y: '25'
  },
  {
    x: '2019',
    y: '5'
  },
  {
    x: '2020',
    y: '40'
  },
  {
    x: '2021',
    y: '50'
  },
  {
    x: '2022',
    y: '15'
  },
];


//expense chart 2
//for Expense chart 2
const days = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 18
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-02 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-03 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 6
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-04 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 9
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-05 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-06 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-07 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 9
  },
];
const months = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-01-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-02-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-03-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 10
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-04-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 5
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-06-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-07-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 15
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-08-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 0
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-09-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 60
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-10-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 55
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-11-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-12-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 10
  },
];
const years = [{
    x: '2018',
    y: '15'
  },
  {
    x: '2019',
    y: '5'
  },
  {
    x: '2020',
    y: '25'
  },
  {
    x: '2021',
    y: '50'
  },
  {
    x: '2022',
    y: '40'
  },
];
//for Income
const days1 = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-02 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 18
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-03 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 9
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-04 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 6
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-05 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-06 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-07 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 7
  },
];
const months1 = [{
    x: Date.parse('2022-01-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-02-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 0
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-03-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 13
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-04-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 4
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-06-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-07-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-08-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-09-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-10-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 50
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-11-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: Date.parse('2022-12-01 00:00:00 UTC+05:00'),
    y: 20
  },
];
const years1 = [{
    x: '2018',
    y: '40'
  },
  {
    x: '2019',
    y: '50'
  },
  {
    x: '2020',
    y: '25'
  },
  {
    x: '2021',
    y: '5'
  },
  {
    x: '2022',
    y: '15'
  },
];

//for Expense 1 chart
// setup
const data = {
  //labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Miscellaneous',
      data: day,
      backgroundColor: [
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: 'Administrative',
      data: day1,
      backgroundColor: [
        '#01AF53',
        '#01AF53',
        '#01AF53',
        '#01AF53',
        '#01AF53',
        '#01AF53'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        '#01AF53',
        '#01AF53',
        '#01AF53',
        '#01AF53',
        '#01AF53',
        '#01AF53'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: 'Payroll',
      data: day2,
      backgroundColor: [
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6',
        '#8D68A6'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: 'Petty Cash',
      data: day3,
      backgroundColor: [
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9',
        '#FD85A9'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
};


// config

var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {

        display: true,
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 60,
          boxHeight: 20,
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        }
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
};


// render init block
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);



function timeFrame(period) {
  console.log(period.value);
  if (period.value == 'day') {
    myChart.config.options.scales.x.time.unit = period.value;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = day;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[1].data = day1;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[2].data = day2;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[3].data = day3;
  }
  if (period.value == 'month') {
    myChart.config.options.scales.x.time.unit = period.value;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = month;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[1].data = month1;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[2].data = month2;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[3].data = month3;
  }
  if (period.value == 'year') {
    myChart.config.options.scales.x.time.unit = period.value;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = year;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[1].data = year1;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[2].data = year2;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[3].data = year3;
  }
  myChart.update();
};

//expense chart 2
//for Expense 1 chart
// setup
const dataExBar = {
  //labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Experience',
      data: days,
      backgroundColor: [
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7',
        '#23BAD7'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
      barThickness: 12
    },
    {
      label: 'Other Income',
      data: days1,
      backgroundColor: [
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153',
        '#00B153'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
      barThickness: 12
    }
  ]
};


// config

var configExBar = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: dataExBar,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {

        display: true,
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 60,
          boxHeight: 20,
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        }
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
};


// render init block
const ExpenseChartTwo = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('ExpenseChartTwo'),
  configExBar
);



function timeFrame2(period2) {
  console.log(period2.value);
  if (period2.value == 'days') {
    ExpenseChartTwo.configExBar.options.scales.x.time.unit = period2.value;
    ExpenseChartTwo.configExBar.dataExBar.datasets[0].data = days;
    ExpenseChartTwo.configExBar.dataExBar.datasets[1].data = days1;
  }
  if (period2.value == 'months') {
    ExpenseChartTwo.configExBar.options.scales.x.time.unit = period2.value;
    ExpenseChartTwo.configExBar.dataExBar.datasets[0].data = months;
    ExpenseChartTwo.configExBar.dataExBar.datasets[1].data = months1;
  }
  if (period2.value == 'years') {
    ExpenseChartTwo.configExBar.options.scales.x.time.unit = period2.value;
    ExpenseChartTwo.configExBar.dataExBar.datasets[0].data = years;
    ExpenseChartTwo.configExBar.data.datasets[1].data = years1;
  }
  ExpenseChartTwo.update();
};
```

```css
.btn-outline-prime {
  color: #23BAD7;
  border-color: #23BAD7;
}

.btn-outline-prime:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #23BAD7;
  border-color: #23BAD7;
}

button.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #23BAD7;
  border-color: #23BAD7;
}

.border-expBox {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0-beta1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


</head>

<body>
  <div class="mb-5">
    <h1>Chart 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 307px" class="row ps-3 pe-3 ms-0 me-0 mb-3 bg-white d-flex align-items-center shadow-sm rounded-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center">
          <div class="col-5 d-flex justify-content-end">
            <button class="active btn btn-outline-prime btn-sm ps-4 pe-4 fw-bold me-2" onclick="timeFrame(this)" value="day">Today</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-prime btn-sm ps-4 pe-4 fw-bold me-2" onclick="timeFrame(this)" value="month">Monthly</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-prime btn-sm ps-4 pe-4 fw-bold" onclick="timeFrame(this)" value="year">Yearly</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="618" height="220" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 130px; width: 250.5px;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="mt-5">
    <h1>Chart 2</h1>
  </div>

  <div style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 307px" class="row ps-3 pe-3 ms-0 me-0  mb-3 bg-white d-flex align-items-center shadow-sm rounded-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex">
          <div class="col-5 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
            <button class="active btn btn-outline-prime btn-sm ps-4 pe-4 fw-bold me-2" onclick="timeFrame2(this);" value="days">Today</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-prime btn-sm ps-4 pe-4 fw-bold me-2" onclick="timeFrame2(this);" value="months">Monthly</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-prime btn-sm ps-4 pe-4 fw-bold" onclick="timeFrame2(this);" value="years">Yearly</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 211px">
      <canvas id="ExpenseChartTwo" width="825" height="211" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 211px; width: 250.5px;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0-beta1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`chartfour` is the name of the chart configuration you're using for creating your chart. `myChart2.chartfour` however does not exist.

When creating the chart, make sur to to assign it to a global constant...

```
const myChart2 = new Chart('myChart2', chartfour);
```

...then, you can directly access its `options` and `data` as follows:

```
myChart2.options.scales.x.time.unit = period.value;
myChart2.data.datasets[0].data = months;
...
```